# node.js permissions for file access

Tags: linux, permissions, node.js

I have a node.js app running that should be able to access a file for reading. As a test, I've set the file to chmod 777 server.log. However, when I try to write to it using fs.appendFile(), I get an EACCESS error on the file. If I run the app using sudo (which I don't want to do), there is no problem with access. However, I am using authbind to gain port access etc. and when using that, this problem appears. 
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just had the wrong path. Works like a charm now :)